# What did I do wrong converting from rectangular complex coordinate to polar?

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

We start with $$\frac{(-15j+15)(12Mj+16M)}{9M+16M}$$
where M standing for $10^6$, and $j=\sqrt{-1}$.

After multiplying, I get $$\frac{180M-240Mj+180Mj+240M}{25M}$$
Then, $$\frac{420M-60Mj}{25M}$$.
This is in the fourth quadrand. The vector is magnitude is $17M$. And the angle is $-8.13^{\circ}$, so $17M\angle-8.13^{\circ}$, in polar notation.

But if I converted all the rectangular notations into polar first, I would get something different. I can't spot my arithmetic error.

$$-15j+15=15 \angle {-45^{\circ}}$$
$$12Mj+16M=20M \angle {53^{\circ}}$$
$$25M=25\angle0^{\circ}$$

So put them all together:

$$\frac{(15 \angle {-45^{\circ}})(20M \angle {53^{\circ}})}{25\angle0^{\circ}}$$

To multiply in polar, I multipled the magnitudes together, and added the angles. To divide, I divide the top magnitude by the bottom magnitude, and substract the bottom angle from the top angle. But I got $12M\angle8^{\circ}$

Comment: Note that $|-15j+15| = 15 \color{red}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$12Mj + 16M = 20M\angle 36^\circ$, looks like you mixed up $y$ and $x$ for arctan. Also, $-15j + 15 = (15\sqrt{2})\angle-45^\circ$, not $15\angle-45^\circ$. I think those are the only two mistakes.